# Is there any performance benefit of using ENUM instead of TinyInt in big data for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, enum, performance-tuning, query-performance

I read a lot of articles about ENUM. but most of them are comparing ENUM to joins not tinyint.

I need fields with 2-5 different statuses.
In this situation is there any performance or storage benefit or drawback of using ENUM?

Comment: I think the answer is "No". Anyway when processing the query ENUM is treated as SMALLINT UNSIGNED (except compare - in that case the string-type compare may decrease performance). And what's a profit? minus 1 small table?

Comment: There have been several Q&A on the ENUM vs TINYINT vs VARCHAR in stackoverflow.com

Comment: The _performance_ difference is insignificant.  The _coding_ difference _may_ be worth picking one over the other.